# How to save form data from <t:dataTable> in JSF 1.2

Tags: forms, datatable, save, jsf-1.2, postconstruct

I am trying to save the data edited in a t:dataTable object when a user clicks on a Save button h:commandButton.  However, before the action is called, the postConstruct() method in the bean is called which tries to load the data for the table, but does not have the docId that was initially passed in.  I have tried using f:param in the h:commandButton to pass in the docId, but that does not work.  Does anyone have the correct strategy for loading the page with a docId, then saving the changes once the save button is clicked?  The following is my current bean code and xhtml.  I do not have the option of upgrading to JSF 2.0 yet unfortunately.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <t:outputText value="Document: #{documentWorkflowCommentsBean.document.name}" />
  <br/><br/>
  <t:dataTable id="commentTable" sortable="false" 
               value="${documentWorkflowCommentsBean.document.workflowComments}"
         var="comment"
         styleClass="addmTable">
    <t:column styleClass="commentId">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="ID" />
      </f:facet>
      <t:outputText value="${comment.commentId}"/>                              
    </t:column>
    <t:column styleClass="cr624_wrap cr624_maxwidth200">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Reviewer" />
      </f:facet>
<t:outputText value="${comment.reviewer}"/>                          
    </t:column>
    <t:column styleClass="charColumn">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Type" />
      </f:facet>
<t:outputText value="${comment.commentType}" 
                    rendered="${!documentWorkflowCommentsBean.editComments}"/>
<t:selectOneListbox id="typeList" title="Choose Comment type"
                          size="1" rendered="${documentWorkflowCommentsBean.editComments}"
                          value="${comment.commentType}">
        <f:selectItems value="${documentWorkflowCommentsBean.commentTypes}"/>
      </t:selectOneListbox>                            
    </t:column>
    <t:column styleClass="cr624_wrap cr624_maxwidth200">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Page" />
      </f:facet>
<t:outputText value="${comment.pageNumber}"/>                          
    </t:column>
    <t:column styleClass="cr624_wrap cr624_maxwidth200">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Section/Paragraph" />
      </f:facet>
      <t:outputText value="${comment.sectionParagraph}"/>                          
    </t:column>
    <t:column styleClass="cr624_wrap cr624_maxwidth200">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Comment/Rationale" />
      </f:facet>
<t:outputText value="${comment.commentRationale}"/>                          
    </t:column>
    <t:column styleClass="cr624_wrap cr624_maxwidth200">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="PO Resolution" />
      </f:facet>
      <t:outputText value="${comment.poResolution}" 
                    rendered="${!documentWorkflowCommentsBean.editComments}"/>
<t:inputTextarea id="poResolutionTextArea" value="${comment.poResolution}" 
                 rendered="${documentWorkflowCommentsBean.editComments}"
           rows="3" cols="20"/>
    </t:column>
    <t:column styleClass="charColumn">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Decision" />
      </f:facet>
<t:outputText value="${comment.decision}" 
                    rendered="${!documentWorkflowCommentsBean.editComments}"/>
<t:selectOneListbox id="decisionList" title="Choose Decision"
                          size="1" rendered="${documentWorkflowCommentsBean.editComments}"
                          value="${comment.decision}">
        <f:selectItems value="${documentWorkflowCommentsBean.commentDecisions}"/>
      </t:selectOneListbox>                         
    </t:column>
  </t:dataTable>     
  <br/>
  <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{documentWorkflowCommentsBean.saveDocumentComments}">
    <f:param name="docId" value="#{documentWorkflowCommentsBean.documentId"/>
    <f:param name="editComments" value="#{documentWorkflowCommentsBean.editComments}"/>
  </h:commandButton>
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" title="Close the dialog" onclick="closeModal();"/>
</h:form>

public class DocumentWorkflowCommentsBean extends PageBean {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -866249792018248429L;
  private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(DocumentWorkflowCommentsBean.class);

  /**
   * Holds a reference to the DocumentBusiness object.
   * 
   * @uml.property name="docBiz"
   */
  private DocumentBusiness docBiz;

  /**
   * This represents the documentId parameter passed
   * 
   * @uml.property name="documentId"
   */
  private long documentId;

  /**
   * This is the corresponding Document object represented by the documentId property
   * 
   * @uml.property name="document"
   */
  private Document document;

  /**
   * Determines if the Type, Resolution, and Decision fields are editable
   * 
   * @uml.property name="editComments"
   */
  private boolean editComments = false;

  private static final List<SelectItem> COMMENT_TYPES = Arrays.asList(new SelectItem("C", "C"),
        new SelectItem("M", "M"),
        new SelectItem("S", "S"),
        new SelectItem("A", "A"));   

  private static final List<SelectItem> COMMENT_DECISIONS = Arrays.asList(
        new SelectItem("A", "A"),
        new SelectItem("R", "R"),
        new SelectItem("M", "M"));

  /**
   * This is called after all resources are injected
   */
  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    docBiz = BusinessUtils.getDocumentBusiness();

    // Get the parameters that are passed in
    String docIdString = (String) getPassedParam("docId");
    String editString = (String) getPassedParam("editComments");

    // editComments will be null when closing dialog
    if (editString != null) {
      editComments = Boolean.parseBoolean(editString);
    }

    if (docIdString != null) {
      try {
        // Retrieve the Document object
  documentId = Long.parseLong(docIdString);
} catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        // do nothing
  log.error("Invalid parameter - " + docIdString);
}

      if (documentId > 0) {
        //lazy load of workflow comments to be displayed
  document = docBiz.getDocumentFetchWorkflowComments(documentId); 
}

// Check to see that the Document exists
if (document == null) {
  this.getAddmSessionBean().addPageErrorMessage("Cannot perform action - document has been deleted.");
}
    }
  }

  public String saveDocumentComments() {
    docBiz.updateDocument(document); //JPA merge call on document
    return null;
  }

  public long getDocumentId() {
    return documentId;
  }

  public void setDocumentId(long documentId) {
    this.documentId = documentId;
  }

  public Document getDocument() {
    return document;
  }

  public void setDocument(Document document) {
    this.document = document;
  }

  public List<SelectItem> getCommentTypes() {
    return COMMENT_TYPES;
  }

  public List<SelectItem> getCommentDecisions() {
    return COMMENT_DECISIONS;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're apparently already using Tomahawk, you can just simulate the JSF 2.x view scope using `<t:saveState>`.

Put this somewhere in the view to make a JSF 1.x request scoped bean to behave like a JSF 2.x view scoped bean:

```html
<t:saveState value="#{documentWorkflowCommentsBean}" />
```

This way the bean will live as long as you interact with the same view by postbacks returning `void`/`null` and it won't be reconstructed/reinitialized on every postback, exactly like as in JSF 2.x.